# Not getting the display/echo expedcted

Tags: php, mysql

And I am running a SELECT code on a MYSQL table

### I have a MYSQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
wf_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
session varchar(255) NOT NULL,
s varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
time timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
menudate varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
mainitemname1 varchar(160) DEFAULT NULL,
mainitemdescription1 varchar(350) DEFAULT NULL,
mainitemtype1 varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
mainitemname2 varchar(160) DEFAULT NULL,
mainitemdescription2 varchar(350) DEFAULT NULL,
mainitemtype2 varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
dessert varchar(320) DEFAULT NULL,
dessertnsa varchar(320) DEFAULT NULL,
mainitemcomment varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

And I am running the following SELECT code on it:

```
$sql=" SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mainitemtype1 like ``'%".o."%'   
OR mainitemtype2 like '%".o."%'      
AND mainitemtype1 NOT like '%".m."%'   
OR mainitemtype1 NOT   like '%".p."%'   
OR mainitemtype1 NOT like '%".c."%'    
OR   mainitemtype1 NOT like '%".s."%'    
AND mainitemtype2 NOT like '%".m."%'   
OR mainitemtype2 NOT   like '%".p."%'   
OR mainitemtype2 NOT like '%".c."%'    
OR mainitemtype2 NOT like '%".s."%' ";
```

---

### I want to display/echo on a web page only the mainitemtype1 and mainitemtype2   that are of the o type (there are 5 different types of mainitemtype   classifications [o,s,m,c,p] and below is the code I am using but it does not    display what I want. Is what I want possible?

```
<?php
$no     = 1;
$total  = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
$amount  = $row['amount'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['amount']) 
if ($row['mainitemtype1'] == o OR $row['mainitemtype2'] == o)
{
echo '<tr>
<td><strong><font color=red> (start new record)</strong> </font> '.$row['menudate'].'</td>
<td><strong>'.$row['mainitemname1'].'  ('.$row['mainitemtype1'].') AND &nbsp; &nbsp; '.$row['mainitemname2'].'   ('.$row['mainitemtype2'].')</strong></td>                  
</tr>';
}
# $total += $row['amount'];
# $no++;
}?>
```

You can see the results by going to http://www.marscafe.com/php/wfdinner_ALL_DINNER_results25-9.12(IF).php

Comment: update  your question add  a proper data sample .. your actual result and your actual result

Comment: What are you comparing in `$row['mainitemtype1'] == o` - that is not a `0`!

Comment: Your PHP code contains many single letter constants and I'm sure it's a typo. If you aren't getting *undefined constant* messages you need to stop and configure error reporting.

Comment: Ok and thank you all. I edited my post and added a link that is hopefully informative showing the results. BTW I am not getting any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only the rows  with only the `o` type 
you could try

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE  mainitemtype1 like concat('%', 'o', '%') 
OR mainitemtype2 like concat('%', 'o', '%') 
AND  NOT  (
    mainitemtype1  like concat('%', 'm', '%') 
    OR mainitemtype2 like concat('%', 'm', '%') 
    OR mainitemtype1  like concat('%', 'p', '%') 
    OR mainitemtype2 like concat('%', 'p', '%') 
    OR mainitemtype1  like concat('%', 'c', '%') 
    OR mainitemtype2 like concat('%', 'c', '%') 
    OR mainitemtype1  like concat('%', 's', '%') 
    OR mainitemtype2 like concat('%', 's', '%') 
)
```

Comment: scaisEdge, thanks for the  help. I used your code and it worked except that it still pulled non o types items and for some reason displays only about half of what the original code did.

Comment: try updated .. you question add a proper data sample  your actual result and your expcted result..